# Rails Render Partial Inside a One Line Block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, enumeration, partials

I've got a feed of information that I want to simplify by using some partials. Basically, I want to do something along the lines of

```
<%= 2.times { |j| render 'item_expanded', item: @social_json_feed[i + j], index: (i + j) } %>
```

However, the above code does not render the partial. Instead, it returns the value "2" two times. If I write the block as a do-end block it works as one would expect.

```
<% 2.times do |j| %>
  <%= render 'item_expanded', item: @social_json_feed[i + j], index: (i + j) %>
<% end %>
```

Produces the partial in the way I want. But if the do-end block works correctly a one-line block should be able to work correctly as well, right? Is it simply something about how the one-line block is formatted or is it something deeper into Rails magic? Also, why does the first example of code return "2" twice??

Comment: What happen if you remove the equal sign? <% 2.times { |j| render 'item_expanded', item: @social_json_feed[i + j], index: (i + j) } %>

Comment: It doesn't render anything. ERB needs to "=" to indicate the logic is supposed to be rendered onto the page.

Answer (score 2):

It's because in first case it renders only return value of `2.times` method call, which is `2`. You should simply use the second notation.

Comment: Yes, this does explain the 22 return. I would love to find a way to do what I want with a one line block though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a call to [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) you should be able to keep it all on one line.

```
<%= 2.times.map { |j| render 'item_expanded', item: @social_json_feed[i + j], index: (i + j) } %>
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, this ends up returning an array with the contents of the partial included as a string x 2. Interesting experiment though.

Comment: What's around this code? It should only render twice. The `i` variable makes me think you've got an outer loop that might account for rendering four times.

Comment: Yeah, its a loop within a loop. The way the feed works requires information to be rendered in a specific manner not possible with one loop. If you like I can push up the full relevant code for the feed.

Comment: That might explain why it's rendering more than twice, but then the question would be why doesn't it do that when you split it over multiple lines?